# There is any event for a Gtk.Button that would execute the code repeatedly while the button is being pressed?

Tags: python, button, python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

There is any event for a Gtk.Button that would execute the code repeatedly while the button is being pressed?

Let's supose I have the following code written in Python 3 and using PyGObject. I'd like to have the message "Hi" been repeadly printed on the screen while the user is holding down the mouse left button over the button (clicking and holding).

There is any other event I can use instead of clicked or any other solution? Thanks.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.button = Gtk.Button("Hi Printer")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(self.button)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Hi")

window = Window()
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapted from [tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tcaswell)'s edited answer, but avoiding the extra call to `print_hi()` after the button is released:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.button = Gtk.Button("Hi Printer")
        self.button.connect("pressed", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.button.connect("released", self.on_button_released)
        self.add(self.button)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        # kick off time out
        timeout = 50
        self._timeout_id = GObject.timeout_add(timeout, self.print_hi)

    def on_button_released(self, widget):
        # remove timeout
        GObject.source_remove(self._timeout_id)
        self._timeout_id = 0 # better safe than sorry

    def print_hi(self):
        print 'hi'
        # repeat until the source is removed
        return True

window = Window()
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thanks Tristan Brindle for the answer and fixing the problem with timeout.

Answer (score 1):

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.button = Gtk.Button("Hi Printer")
        self.button.connect("pressed", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.button.connect("released", self.on_button_released)
        self.add(self.button)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        # arm repeater
        self._repeat = True
        # trigger printing
        self.print_hi()

    def on_button_released(self, widget):
        # disarm repeater
        self._repeat = False

    def print_hi(self):
        print 'hi'
        # tune timeout for repeat rate
        timeout = 50
        # if should still be repeating
        if self._repeat:
            # arm timer, with call back to this function
            GObject.timeout_add(timeout, self.print_hi)

window = Window()
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Issue before is 'clicked' is up-down on the button, 'pressed' is down and 'released' is up.

Also updated to use the correct timer.

It turns out the timeout function in gtk can automatically re-set, so this can be done even more simply:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject


class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.button = Gtk.Button("Hi Printer")
        self.button.connect("pressed", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.button.connect("released", self.on_button_released)
        self.add(self.button)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        # arm repeater
        self._repeat = True
        # kick off time out
        timeout = 50
        GObject.timeout_add(timeout, self.print_hi)

    def on_button_released(self, widget):
        # disarm repeater
        self._repeat = False

    def print_hi(self):
        print 'hi'
        # if should still be repeating
        return self._repeat

window = Window()
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

[example](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/progressbar.html#example)

Comment: You can't call `timeout_add_seconds` with a float. Or, depending on your version, maybe you _can_, but it's still going to run every 1 second, not every 0.5 seconds. If you want to run more than once/second (or just want more precision), you have to use `timeout_add`.

Comment: tcaswell, your solution is not working very well, but looks like the solution would be starting a thread when the button is clicked and stopping it when it's released, right? I also fixed your code and it works on Python 3 and PyGObject not PyGTK.

Comment: @abarnert could you confirm my logic if it's right? "the solution would be starting a thread when the button is clicked and stopping it when it's released"

Comment: @Zignd: There is no need to use a thread just to run code periodically; you're making things more complicated and less efficient for no reason. The basic idea in this answer looks right, even if the details may be wrong. Meanwhile, if you explain what you mean by "not working very well", it might be easier to improve it.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah, I flubbed the details.  I think they are correct now (works on py2.7)

Comment: The above (edited) solution is okay, but it has the disadvantage that the timeout function (`print_hi()`) will still run once after the button has been released. This is probably not noticible with a 50ms repeat interval, but would definitely be annoying with, say, a 1 second delay. A better solution would be to save the return value from `GObject.timeout_add()`, and then call `GObject.source_remove()` with this saved value in your `on_button_released()` function to remove the timeout before it next fires.